# Swap Function - pointers - confusion

Tags: c++, c, pointers

Notice in the code that I am not using pointers, but I had concepts that if I would use this function, the value would return back to normal when the code block is finished.

But the code is compiling with the answer which I would get with pointers actually.

I need help as I am confused if I have foul concept related to pointers.

```
void swap(int i, int j) {
    int temp = i;
    i = j;
    j = temp;
}

int main() {
    int a = 110;
    int b = 786;
    cout << "Before swapping the value" << endl;
    cout << "'a' stores the value : " << a << endl;
    cout << "'b' stores the value : " << b << endl;
    swap(a,b);
    cout << "\nAfter swapping the value" << endl;
    cout << "'a' stores the value : " << a << endl;
    cout << "'b' stores the value : " << b << endl;
    swap(a, b);
    cout << "\nAnd back again swapping the value" << endl;
    cout << "'a' stores the value : " << a << endl;
    cout << "'b' stores the value : " << b << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[I am getting results without using pointers - is this IDE problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLtJk.png)

Comment: What is the actual output of your program? What output did you expect? Please edit your question to include that.

Comment: Sorry are you claiming that `swap`ing works or not as this does not work: http://ideone.com/xzGMcl as you're passing by value meaning it copies your args and doesn't assign any new value to them

Comment: Perhaps attempt swap with a macro: `#define swap(i,j) do{int temp = i; i = j; j = temp;}while(0)`

Comment: Use `std::swap` to swap values or `std::swap_ranges` to swap more elements using iterators.

Comment: The question here is why the swap seems to work for him. As shown in the screenshot OP posted as comment in an answer. It shouldn't work since he's just swapping in the context of the swap function without passing pointers or references.

Comment: The image you linked in an answer shows several other swap functions - you need to paste the code which gives the results, not some other code.

Comment: Can you post *code* that reproduces the issue rather than a cropped screen shot of a bit of the code?

Comment: Do you declare the `swap` functions before you use them? Are you doing `using namespace std;` at the top? Please create a [Minimal, ***Complete***, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the `iostream` header you included also includes the `utility` header; and you get a definition of `std::swap` pulled into your program.

Since you (don't show it, but probably) have `using namesapce std;` in your code, the overload set for `swap` contains both overloads. And by the rules of overload resolution, the correct<sup>1</sup> overload is called.

---

<sup>1</sup> For some definition of correct, in this case

Comment: gonna change the function name  and check it

Comment: I created a project in Visual Studio 2013 with including the `iostream` header and `using namespace std;` I cannot reproduce OP's problem. The swap doesn't work which is the predicted behavior.

Comment: @Philipp, you cannot assume any standard header includes others unless the standard guarantees it (which it doesn't in this case). [GCC reproduces it](http://ideone.com/k19F60), for instance.

Comment: Thanks bro, this was the part i was missing. I have changed the function name, and its returning me the original values as it should have.

Comment: @BaqarHussain, you don't have to give up simple names for you classes and functions, that's what [namespace](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace)s are for :)

Comment: @StoryTeller Neatly spotted! :)

Comment: @StoryTeller I see. So even within Visual Studio this could vary?

Comment: @StoryTeller i am new with c++, had to learn it bcoz of my degree, i am working around it, and this community seems awesome :)

Comment: @Philipp, Yup. A vendor update can mess up your codebase if you aren't careful. That's why you should always (1) include everything you need explicitly and (2) partition your code into namespaces to avoid collisions.

Comment: @StoryTeller Nice, learned something important today then! :)

Comment: @BaqarHussain If you're learning C++ and want to do it properly, we have a list of [good C++ books](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1782465) which you might want to look into.

Comment: @Angew btw i am doing c++ practice by watching pluralsight c++ paths, and reading this book "C-Plus-Plus-How-to-Program-8th-Edition-Paul-Deitel-Harvey-Deitel" - kindly guide me, as i get overwhelmed quite easily

Answer (score 6):

Your `swap` function will not swap the values in the scope of `main`, because `i` and `j` are *function local variables*. To get the behavior you expect, you should pass by reference.

```
void swap(int& i, int& j) {
    int temp = i;
    i = j;
    j = temp;
}
```

Your code will [not actually swap the values](http://cpp.sh/2ksp).

**Guess**:
I think that you are `using namespace std;` and from one of your `#include` from the standard library you are colliding with [`std::swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap). I think the `std::` version of the function is being called in your case, that is the only reason your code appears to "work".

Comment: Thats the point, here is the picture after compiling - its giving me perfect answers- http://imgur.com/a/qc8jP

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use pointers to swap, you should pass by pointers:

```
void swap(int *a, int*b)
{
  int temp = *a;
  *a = *b;
  *b = temp;
}
```

Passing by reference is another option, as another user has pointed out.

PS: Your query has nothing to do with function-pointers, so I'll be removing the function-pointer tag from your query.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked this part.

Comment: I was using this normally, out of curiosity i removed pointers and ended up swapped values, thats why i started this thread :)